# How does Gelato's Relay service work? How is it possible for another wallet to send my signed transaction (matching sender address) and pay gas?

Tags: transactions, gas, smart-contract-wallets, meta-transactions

How does Gelato's Relay service (used by gnosis safe relayer) work? How is it possible for another wallet to send my signed transaction (matching sender address) and pay gas? Does it require Gnosis to have made an integration in their end? Could this be implemented such that no adaptation is needed on the smart contract, maybe through an L2?